# Laravel nova api slow performance

Tags: laravel, performance, laravel-8, pagespeed, laravel-nova

Currently, I have a laravel nova application on a vps, since the domain is linked to the server the performace is very low.
All the requests that are slow come from nova-api, they take 15 to 20 seconds per request. I have attached a screenshot that shows the problem.
I don't have much experience with this myself. So I was wondering if more people have had this problem and have a good solution for it

[screenshot of loading times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8cDI.png)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Xdebug is not active on your server.